# Text and image side by side in Quarto column layout

Tags: layout, markdown, multiple-columns, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to have a picture on the left side of a slide, and text on the right side. I am using Quarto `reveal.js`.

I would expect that with the `.columns` div, it should work, but this gives unexpected result. Same with using `layout-ncol=2`. Any ideas?

A reproducible example:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

::: {layout-ncol=2}

Some text that is very long and that should take most of the column space.

![](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)

Some other text that should be below the first paragraph.

:::

## Another title

:::: .columns
::: {.column width=60%}

Some text that is very long and that should take most of the column space.

:::

::: {.column width=40%}

![](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)

:::
::::
```

| First slide | Second slide |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotation marks are missing, e.g. `width=40` needs to be changed to `width="40%"`:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

::: columns
::: {.column width="40%"}

![](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)
:::

::: {.column width="60%"}

Some text that is very long and that should take most of the column space.

<br>

Some other text that should be below the first paragraph.

:::
:::
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Well what is wrong with my code then?

Comment: It seems that the percentage `width="20%"` needs to be in quotation marks..

Comment: Right!! Learning a "new" language always boils down to those little details

Comment: You also confused me with 'have a picture on the left side of a slide' and you put it on the right in your example :D